# Table Formatting problem in my new design

Tags: tables, beamer, formatting

I want to increase the width of left column of table in the same design.

MWE

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\usefonttheme{structurebold}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,82,155}

\mode<presentation> {

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\usecolortheme[named=myblue]{structure}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % To remove the navigation symbols from the bottom of all slides uncomment this line
}
\setbeamerfont{table}{size=\footnotesize}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\tcbset{tab1/.style={fonttitle=\bfseries\small,fontupper=\footnotesize\rmfamily,
colback=green!10!white,colframe=red!75!black,colbacktitle=green!40!white,
coltitle=black,center title,freelance,frame code={
\foreach \n in {north east,north west,south east,south west}
{\path [fill=green!75!black] (interior.\n) circle (2mm); };},}}

\tcbset{tab2/.style={enhanced,fonttitle=\bfseries,fontupper=\footnotesize\rmfamily,
colback=green!10!white,colframe=red!50!black,colbacktitle=Salmon!40!white,
coltitle=black,center title}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{tcolorbox}[tab1,tabularx={X||Y||Y}]
\textbf{ Description} & {1st Revised} & 2nd Revision    \\\hline\hline
 \textbf{Construction Cost} & 598.762 & 620.991 \\\hline
{ 10\% External Development Charges} & 54.449 & 56.398\\\hline
 \textbf{Sub Total} & 653.211& 677.388 \\\hline\hline
 Price variation of allotted works  & {} & 6.502\\\hline
 Price variation of allotted works G-1 &{} & 0.946\\\hline
 External Electric connection payable to WAPDA & 5.000 & 5.000\\\hline
Add for Sui Gas connection charges & 3.000 & 3.000\\\hline
2\% Consultancy fee for resident supervision&13.064&13.548\\\hline
1\% for Tree Planation & 6.532 & 6.774\\\hline
5\% PST& {-}&8.654\\\hline\hline
Grand Total &671.346 &721.813\\\hline\hline

\end{tcolorbox}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you'll like it:

[image]

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames, table}]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\usefonttheme{structurebold}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,82,155}

\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme[named=myblue]{structure}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % To remove the navigation symbols from the bottom of all slides uncomment this line
}
\setbeamerfont{table}{size=\footnotesize}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcx{O{X}m}
    % O: optional, if it is not given, than is used default in {...}
    % m: mandatory
    {\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\bfseries}#1}{#2}}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\tcbset{tab1/.style={fonttitle=\bfseries\small,fontupper=\footnotesize\rmfamily,
colback=green!10!white,colframe=red!75!black,colbacktitle=green!40!white,
coltitle=black,center title,freelance,frame code={
\foreach \n in {north east,north west,south east,south west}
{\path [fill=green!75!black] (interior.\n) circle (2mm); };},}}

\tcbset{tab2/.style={enhanced,fonttitle=\bfseries,fontupper=\footnotesize\rmfamily,
colback=green!10!white,colframe=red!50!black,colbacktitle=Salmon!40!white,
coltitle=black,center title}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\sisetup{group-four-digits}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[tab1,tabularx={l || S[table-format=6.0]|| S[table-format=6.3] }]
\textbf{Description}    & \mcx[X||]{1st Revised} & \mcx{2nd Revision}    \\
    \hline\hline
\textbf{Construction Cost} 
                        & 598 762           & 620 991               \\
    \hline
\SI{10}{\%} External Development Charges
                        & 54 449            &  56 398               \\
    \hline
\textbf{Sub Total}      & 653 211           & 677 388               \\
    \hline\hline
Price variation of allotted works  
                        & {--}              & 6 502                 \\
    \hline
Price variation of allotted works G-1 
                        & {--}              &   0.946               \\
    \hline
External Electric connection payable to WAPDA 
                        &   5 000           &   5 000               \\
    \hline
Add for Sui Gas connection charges 
                        &   3 000           &   3 000               \\
    \hline
\SI{2}{\%} Consultancy fee for resident supervision
                        &  13 064           &  13 548               \\
    \hline
\SI{1}{\%} for Tree Planation 
                        &   6 532           &   6 774               \\
    \hline
\SI{5}{\%} PST          & {--}              &   8 654               \\
    \hline\hline
\textbf{Grand Total}    & 671 346           & 721 813               \\
    \hline\hline
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank u very much for your kind cooperation. You have solved my issue in a beautiful way. Best Wishes!

Answer (score 1):

Just change the first column width which you assigned at `\begin{tcolorbox}[tab1,tabularx={l||Y||Y}]` from `X` to `l` like that

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[tab1,tabularx={l||Y||Y}]
```

You get the output like this

[image]

Keeping the three columns at `X` and `Y` widths will ensure that the three columns widths are equal, which you don't want. Assigning `l` for the first column width will let have its normal content width without breaking its cells lines, and then only equate widths of the 2nd and 3rd columns.

Comment: Thank u very much Dear for your kind cooperation. You have nailed it. Best Wishes for u!